# How to solve errors when release apk in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting error when release apk in flutter.

```
PS C:\AndroidStudioProjects\player mayan> flutter build apk --split-per-abi --no-tree-shake-icons

Building without sound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.7.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.     
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.                    
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.16.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.16.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\streamhandler\TransactionStreamHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_analytics-7.0.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseanalytics\FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.20.0+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\auth\FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.  
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.                
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_dynamic_links-0.7.0+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebasedynamiclinks\FirebaseDynamicLinksPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_remote_config-0.6.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firebaseremoteconfig\FirebaseRemoteConfigPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-7.0.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin.java:38: warning: [deprecation] Registrar 
in PluginRegistry has been deprecated
  public static void registerWith(PluginRegistry.Registrar registrar) { 
                                                ^
1 warning                                                               
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_sign_in-4.5.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlesignin\GoogleSignInPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.                    
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:9: warning: [deprecation] AsyncTask in android.os has been deprecated
import android.os.AsyncTask;
                 ^
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:121: warning: [deprecation] AsyncTask 
in android.os has been deprecated
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
        ^
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:121: warning: [deprecation] AsyncTask() in AsyncTask has been deprecated
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
    ^
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:123: warning: [deprecation] doInBackground(Params...) in AsyncTask has been deprecated
      protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                        ^
  where Params,Result are type-variables:
    Params extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
    Result extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:121: warning: [deprecation] AsyncTask() in AsyncTask has been deprecated
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
                                         ^
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:128: warning: [deprecation] onPostExecute(Result) in AsyncTask has been deprecated
      protected void onPostExecute(Boolean value) {
                     ^
  where Result is a type-variable:
    Result extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:131: warning: [deprecation] execute(Params...) in AsyncTask has been deprecated
    }.execute();
     ^
  where Params,Progress,Result are type-variables:
    Params extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
    Progress extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
    Result extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
7 warnings
AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #7: Unexpected standard output: Ready
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':cloud_firestore:verifyReleaseResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':cloud_firestore:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform play-services-base-17.0.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\player mayan\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\182d559fc8f5b90b025f205266ad0e02\jetified-play-services-base-17.0.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.       
   > Failed to transform play-services-base-17.0.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\player mayan\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\182d559fc8f5b90b025f205266ad0e02\jetified-play-services-base-17.0.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform play-services-base-17.0.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\player mayan\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\182d559fc8f5b90b025f205266ad0e02\jetified-play-services-base-17.0.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.       

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1h 43m 34s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                    6269.4s
The build failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try usingJetifier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin cloud_firestore...
The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.
```

How to solve it?
Why am getting those errors?
Do i wanna update something?
When I run on emulator, its working properly without errors but only getting errors when I release.
I checked some answers but not clear. I used cloud_firestore dependencies as "null" in pubspec file.
Do i wanna update it?
Kindly guide me to solve these errors.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you building your app without null safety i recommend you to migrate your project to null safety and use packages that they support  null safety.
Otherwise did you try running flutter clean and build your application again?

Comment: I tired flutter clean but i got same error so i tired another method last day. I downgrade share preference ^0.5.12+4 to shared_preferences: ^0.5.1+2 after that I opened my flutter application in android studio to gradle. Finally now it's working fine. I'm sorry, i forgot to inform you because I got confused more than 4 days.

Comment: I thought those errors because of cloud firebase too. But downgrading shared preference helped me to solve these errors.